# Types in C Macros

Tags: c, macros, types

I am trying my hand out in C and I thought it would be prudent to write the following macros:

```
// takes address of a variable and passes it on as a void*
#define vp_pack(v) ((void*)&x)

// takes a void pointer and dereferences it to t
#define vp_upack(v,t) (*((t*)v))
```

And I test it out like this:

```
int
main()
{
    int five = 5;
    char a = 'a';

    vp ptr;

    // Test 1
    ptr = vp_pack(five);
    if(vp_unpack(ptr,int) == five)
        printf("Test 1 passed\n");
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Test 1: all is doomed\n");

    // Test 2
    ptr = vp_pack(a);
    if(vp_unpack(ptr,char) == a)
        printf("Test 2 passed\n");
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Test 2: all is doomed!\n");
}
```

But `gcc` spews out obscenities like `error: expected expression before 'int'` at me.

I've spent an entire day on this, and still can't understand, what is wrong with the code. Could any one explain this to me?

Also, I am not a programmer by profession. I don't even work in IT, but this is my hobby. So if some one could tell me a better way to do this, please do so.

Thanks!

Comment: `#define vp_pack(v) ((void*)&x)` looks wrong is it a typo? x!=v

Comment: Yes it was. The answer below is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did should work, you just have two little typos :

```
#define vp_pack(v) ((void*)&v)
#define vp_unpack(v,t) (*((t*)v))
```

First line had `x` instead of `v`, and second was named `vp_upack`.